# Эффект неона в Unity

Tags: unity3d, svg, svg-animation

Помогите реализовать эффект неона в Unity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Эффект неонового свечения может быть реализован с помощью SVG фильтров:

`feGaussianBlur`, `feComponentTransfer`, `feMergeNode`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300">
  
  <filter id="neon">
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(255,255,128)" flood-opacity="0.5" in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
    <feComponentTransfer result="glow1">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="4" intercept="0" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
       <feMergeNode in="glow1" />
       <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="100" font-family="sans-serif" x="50%" y="200" fill="yellow" filter="url(#neon)">NEON</text>
</svg>
```

У SVG фильтров можно анимировать многие атрибуты.
Например в примере выше у фильтра `feGaussianBlur` будет анимирован атрибут `stdDeviation`

```
<animate attributeName="stdDeviation" dur="6s" begin="0s"
 values="3;10;10;3;3" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300">
  
  <filter id="neon">
    <feFlood flood-color="rgb(155,243,233)" flood-opacity="0.5" in="SourceGraphic" />
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" >
       <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" dur="6s" begin="0s" values="3;10;10;3;3" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </feGaussianBlur>
    <feComponentTransfer result="glow1">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="4" intercept="0" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
       <feMergeNode in="glow1" />
       <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="100" font-family="sans-serif" x="50%" y="200" fill="#507D78" filter="url(#neon)">NEON</text>
</svg>
```

**Другой вариант решения**

С помощью фильтров `feGaussianBlur` и  `feColorMatrix`

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#red-glow);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- размытие текста на разных уровнях-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
      <!-- объединить все размытия, кроме первого -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- перекрасить объединенные пятна в cyan цвет-->
      <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 1 0 0 0
                             0 0 1 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <text x="200" y="200" text-anchor="middle">Neon</text>
</svg>
```

Меняя коэффициенты матрицы у фильтра `feColorMatrix` можно практически получить любой цвет неонового свечения:

**Зелёный неон**

```html
<style>
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#red-glow);
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- размытие текста на разных уровнях-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
      <!-- объединить все размытия, кроме первого -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- перекрасить объединенные пятна в cyan цвет-->
      <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 1 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <text x="200" y="200" text-anchor="middle">Neon</text>
</svg>
```

**Фиолетовый неон**

```html
<style>
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sansserif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#red-glow);
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <filter id="red-glow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
       <!-- размытие текста на разных уровнях-->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur5"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur10"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20" result="blur20"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="30" result="blur30"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blur50"/>
      <!-- объединить все размытия, кроме первого -->
      <feMerge result="blur-merged">
        <feMergeNode in="blur10"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur20"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur30"/>
        <feMergeNode in="blur50"/>
      </feMerge>
      <!-- перекрасить объединенные пятна в cyan цвет-->
      <feColorMatrix result="red-blur" in="blur-merged" type="matrix"
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 1 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="red-blur"/>       
        <feMergeNode in="blur5"/>          
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <text x="200" y="200" text-anchor="middle">Neon</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этой ветке последний пост предлагают решение) Попробуйте, в теории все так и должно работать
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151845/how-to-make-neon-lightning-effect-in-unity-3d

Answer (score 0):

Этот эффект называется Bloom и добивается он путем освещения и пост-обработки. Вот статья: 
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/post-processing-effects-bloom 
Также, можете попробовать зайти в unity asset store и поискать asset на эту тему, их там достаточно много в том числе и бесплатных.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать шейдеры для достижения этого эффекта.
Порядок действий следующий:

1. Создайте новый шейдер и замените содержимое этого шейдера на приведённый код ниже.
2. Создайте новый материал и выберете ему шейдер, который вы создали.
3. Теперь используйте материал с raw image, предварительно указав текстуру для материала в параметре Texture.

```
Shader "Glow" 
{
     Properties {
         _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
         _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
         _Glow ("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
     }

     SubShader {
         Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }

         LOD 100
         Cull Off
         ZWrite On
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

         Pass {
             CGPROGRAM
                 #pragma vertex vert
                 #pragma fragment frag

                 sampler2D _MainTex;
                 half4 _MainTex_ST;
                 fixed4 _Color;
                 half _Glow;

                 struct vertIn {
                     float4 pos : POSITION;
                     half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                 };

                 struct v2f {
                     float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                     half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                 };

                 v2f vert (vertIn v) {
                     v2f o;
                     o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.pos);
                     o.tex = v.tex * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
                     return o;
                 }

                 fixed4 frag (v2f f) : SV_Target {
                     fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, f.tex);
                     col *= _Color;
                     col *= _Glow;
                     return col;
                 }
             ENDCG
         }
     }}
```